# Asking for a review in a comment in another post

Tags: discussion

I searched FAQ and existing posts for similar language, but did not find a duplicate - apologies if this has already been asked and answered.

I posted a Java class for review.  I read and adhered to suggestions for writing quality posts.  A couple days passed with no responses, comments or votes, so I added a bounty (I had 75 rep and used 50 for the bounty).  While that was very recent, I'm not confident it'll receive any replies.

So my question is: is it considered bad form to ask a user in a comment in another post (not mine) to review my existing post?  E.g., User A posts, User B provides a nice response.  Can I add a comment to User B's response asking User B to review my (unrelated) post?

Comment: This question made me ask a FAQ question: [How to draw more attention to a question?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6822/31562)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that would likely be considered bad form. Please avoid that.

However, you are free to head into chat [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) and mention your post. Don't push it too far though, you cannot force anyone to review your code and there are many posts waiting to be reviewed.

Answer (score 4):

It's great that you've read the help pages and that you're making an effort to improve the quality of your questions, and it shows.
Unfortunately, sometimes you need a bit of luck to get noticed,
and I think that's just what happened.

> A couple days passed with no responses, comments or votes, so I added a bounty (I had 75 rep and used 50 for the bounty). While that was very recent, I'm not confident it'll receive any replies.

I'm confident you will receive answers by the time the bounty expires. Hopefully some of them will be good.

As @Simon said, you can mention your post in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) to attract attention, as long as you don't overdo it.

Comments on posts are intended to be related to the question/answer, so strictly speaking, a comment to draw attention to an unrelated post is not really appropriate.