# How can I make my question get more attention?

Tags: discussion, faq, questions

I have written a question that hasn't gotten an answer in several days, and there's not much activity on my question (votes, views, comments).

What can I do to draw more attention to my question?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a common problem on Code Review, as we have plenty of [unanswered questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered).

While you are waiting for a review, and to increase the probability that your question will be answered sooner, there are a couple of things you can do:

#### Improve your question

See [Simon's guide for asking a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562) for several tips on how to improve your question. Be sure to have a high quality question before trying the other tips. You should be proud of your question.

Editing a question will [bump it on the front page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) and good quality questions are more likely to receive the answer that you want. Please avoid editing your question too often, and make sure that your edits improve the question.

#### Bounty

Stack Exchange has a [bounty system](/help/bounty) that allows you to offer up some of your reputation to draw attention to your question and award it to someone who answers your question.

#### Chat

You can head into [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) (Code Review official chat room) and mention your post. Just be sure to not push it too far, as that might upset some of the regulars in the room. Remember that you cannot force anyone to review your code and there are many posts waiting to be reviewed.

#### Answer another question

If you answer someone else's question and review their code, that will increase the probability that someone who's out looking for unanswered questions to answer will find and review your code and post an answer.

You might think that you're not good enough (yet) to post an answer, but reviewing code and posting answers is another way to increase your skill.

---

## Things to not do

Please **don't try to contact specific users in other ways.** Do NOT lookup someone on Facebook. Do NOT send an e-mail asking a random user to answer your question (whether it's on Code Review or Stack Overflow or elsewhere in the Stack Exchange network).

It is also [bad form](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6819/31562) to post a comment on other users' unrelated posts asking them to review your code.

Comment: Can you post this as a [proposed Help Center page](/a/5089/9357)?

Comment: The bounty system is unfortunately unavailable to newer users who don't yet have a substantial sum of reputation. It is also hard for new users to get reputation, as the "easy" questions newer programmers/members could answer are taken quickly by the more experienced programmers/members.

Comment: @MichaelBrandonMorris It is true that you need some reputation in order to use the bounty system. One way to earn that reputation is to *post good questions* that become popular and gets upvotes. I believe the easiest way for new users to earn reputation is to ask good questions.

Comment: New users with low rep can also earn credits by doing good edits to unanswered questions.