# How to get more attention to my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions, questions

Let me start off by saying I have already read: [How can I make my question get more attention?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6822/how-can-i-make-my-question-get-more-attention) Because of reading that I have edited my question using the linked post to include more description etc.

---

[This is my question.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154816/single-instancing-class)

I have had a bounty active for a while and edited my question (albeit very recently). I have received what are probably drive by upvotes and a couple of comments from a user but beyond that nothing.

I would prefer not starting another bounty due to my low rep on this site. That is also a part of my reason to try and draw more attention to the question is that I'd hate to see the bounty go unrewarded to someone here.

Is there anything wrong with the question that could be improved? Is there anyway I can attract more attention to the question, aside from what I have already done?

I have also now posted in [The 2nd Monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Comment: Well, posting it either here or in The 2nd definitely helped. You now got an answer :-)

Comment: The question I linked to turned out it had all the information I needed to get more attention, I just needed to be more patient!