# How to improve "Populate a table from a database using JavaScript" question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently had a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156830/populate-a-table-from-a-database-using-javascript-from-a-jquery-ui-dialog-box) receive fairly low attention (25 views, 1 comment, and 0 answers). It seems reasonably tagged, I'm familiar with bounties, and I've already read [the FAQ on how to attract attention to a question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6822/how-can-i-make-my-question-get-more-attention).

The question hasn't been upvoted or downvoted.

Can this question be improved (specifically with the goal of increasing the chance of getting a good answer)?