# Should I post about my design and architectural concerns on Code Review or Software Engineering?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've developed an application and I'd like to know if I've done it well. But my main concerns are not really about the code itself, which is quite simple, but more about the design and architecture, present and future.

It's a review of the design, so where's the best place to ask my question?

Comment: As Software Engineers is a tricky site to understand, I've made them aware about this question.

Comment: Related: [Reviewing "design"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1924/31562)

Comment: [Related on Software Engineering meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6502/60171)

Comment: [This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/352038/68834) on SE perfectly highlights the difference between CR and SE as far as *the code in the post* is concerned: if the code is serving as an *illustration*, an *idea*, a *concept*, then the question is probably a better fit for SE.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short answer: Will you be posting your actual existing, working code? If yes, then I believe Code Review is better.

Our help center does state:

> *However, if your question is not about a particular piece of code and instead is a generally applicable question about (...) Higher-level architecture and design of software systems then your question is off-topic for this site.*

which is sometimes understood as "We don't review design here", but what is then mainly missed is the first part: *if your question is **not** about a particular piece of code and instead is a generally applicable question...*.

So basically, if your question **is about a particular piece of code**, then I think Code Review is the best place for it.

Comment: Reviewers can comment on any and all parts of the code, and so the design may not be mentioned. What should people do in those cases?

Comment: @Peilonrayz A bounty is one option. It's basically about [giving your question more attention](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6822/31562) as your specific concern haven't been answered.