# How long does it usually take to get code reviewed on this site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, unanswered-questions

I submitted this [code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/168824/validate-data-in-spreadsheet-checking-for-errors) yesterday, and I am just curious when it would be reviewed.  I was looking forward to learning some new things.

Comment: You might want to read [How can I make my question get more attention?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6822/31562)

Comment: ok, I will do that now

Comment: The chat-active VBA crowd sees every single [tag:vba] question asked on CR, SO and SU in the [VBA Rubberducking](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929) chatroom. *Reviewing* code takes anywhere between 15 minutes and 3 hours or even more, depending on what's going on and how much there is to say about the code being presented (and how much effort reviewers are putting in anyway). Note that Stack Overflow is on a completely different pace; Code Review is much more relaxed; on SO you can get a two-liner answer in two minutes. Here you get a 2-pager answer in two hours, days, ...depends.

Comment: @Mat'sMug And how much time does it take to write an answer compared to a comment...?

Comment: @SimonForsberg IDK... Everytime I try to keep it short and comment-fitting, I end up with a 2-pager answer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a [Stack Exchange Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/211650/average-time-to-first-answer-by-tag), written by @LokiAstari and tweaked by me, showing the average time between the question and the first answer.

As you can see, there can be huge variations.  Depending on how well you phrase the question and how complex the code is, you might get an answer within minutes, or it might never get answered.  If it does get an answer, then a few days is a typical wait.  (Currently, about 10% of all questions are unanswered, or [have no upvoted answer](/q/6959/9357).)